# Is it possible to pass string of ids in Where IN dynamic Soql the dynamic part should accept Set id's and Lis id's

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, set

I have a dynamic soql in where I pass a string of ids in the WHERE IN clause this thtrows me a error:

> expecting a colon, found '{'

My where clause is as follows:

```
WHERE Id IN {x0x0o000000000xXXX}
```

I also tried

```
WHERE Id IN :{x0x0o000000000xXXX}
```

I also tried adding {x0x0o000000000xXXX} to a string and do

```
WHERE IN :String
```

this gives the error:

> IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

So is it not possible to use a string in the SOQL itself and does it has to be :Set or :List?

I get the use of :Set my question is: is it in any way possible to use a string directly in de dynamic soql so use

```
testString = String.valueOf(Set<id>); 
WHERE IN testString
```

Comment: I literally spent 30 secondes to find this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/how-do-i-build-a-soql-query-for-records-in-a-list-of-ids

Comment: @MartinLezer I get the use of :Set<id> my question is: is it in any way possible to use a string directly in de dynamic soql so use testString = String.valueOf(Set<id>); WHERE IN testString

Comment: @RohitMourya  I get the use of :Set<id> my question is: is it in any way possible to use a string directly in de dynamic soql so use testString = String.valueOf(Set<id>); WHERE IN testString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that Rohit's comment serves the right link to get an answer, just some adjusting needed, however, here is the actual code you need:

You have:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{...};
```

You need to convert set to String:

```
String idsString = String.join(new List<Id>(ids), '\',\'');
```

Then you just need to make a query with such where-clause:

```
String whereClause = 'WHERE Id IN (\'' + idsString + '\')';
```